# Mathjax - scale options for inline/block

Tags: scale, mathjax

Hello is it possible to have different scale for inline equations and block equations?
I have scale at 150 % because of inline eq. - I need them big. But then equations that are in block are a way too large.

Can I set scalling individually for inline and block?
For $ \tech $ it would be bigger then for $$ \tech $$

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
"HTML-CSS": {
scale: 150,
},
tex2jax: {
  inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
  displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
},
});
```

Comment: This is something you probably want to ask the MathJax people, so that if there is some way to do this, they add that to the MathJax documentation. (And then add the answer once you have it =)

Comment: Just for reference, I opened a ticket for it: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/313

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built in for this, but you could use something like

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () {
  var TEX = MathJax.InputJax.TeX;
  var PREFILTER = TEX.prefilterMath;
  TEX.Augment({
    prefilterMath: function (math,displaymode,script) {
      if (!displaymode) {math = "\\large{"+math+"}"}
      return PREFILTER.call(TEX,math,displaymode,script);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

to add `\large` in front of every in-line math expression (and set the scaling back to 100%).

If the in-line math isn't large enough, then then may be something in your CSS or your font settings that is causing that.  For example, if you are having to use `<code>` around the math to prevent your mathematics from being tampered with by some markup engine, then the font associated with `<code>` elements will be the one that controls the size of the math (rather than the text that surrounds it).  That could be controlled by the CSS for code blocks, but it can also be set in most browsers as a separate font.  It seems that most browsers are configured with that font being smaller than the regular font (I don't really understand why) and so that could be causing your problem as well.

Comment: Nice hack! I used it to actually make my display blocks bigger and have the inlined ones the same size. But this is invalid TeX, isn't it? Because you can't use \large etc. in math mode. Still, nice!